# Cannot find SwiftUI or Combine types when building Swift package for "Any iOS Device"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift package which supports iOS 10, macOS 10.13, tvOS 10 and watchOS 2. I want this package to expose some SwiftUI functionality which could be used when the referencing module can import SwiftUI. For example, making my package type (`Persisted`) conform to the SwiftUI protocol `DynamicProperty`:

```swift
#if canImport(SwiftUI)
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension Persisted: DynamicProperty { }

#endif
```

With the above in place, the project no longer builds when building for "Any iOS Device (arm64)" - I get the compiler error:

> Cannot find type 'DynamicProperty' in scope

When I change the build target to any iPhone simulator, it builds OK. It also builds OK when building for "Any Mac", "Any tvOS Device", etc. What do I need to do to make the package build for Any iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/l5mt0b/cannot_build_for_any_ios_device_arm64_as_doesnt/), it has to do with the availability of SwiftUI on certain ARM architectures.

The following condition solved the issue for me:

```swift
#if canImport(SwiftUI) && (!os(iOS) || arch(arm64))
```

Comment: When I did this, I ran into the issue that previews no longer work, since those build for iOS with x64 architecture (on non-Apple-Silicon machines). I instead switched it to `!arch(arm)`, excluding 32-bit ARM, and that worked fine.